# How to get data from database by id?

Tags: php, mysql, json

I want to get data from "data_show.php?id=2"

my code below (detail1.php)

```
$mysqli = new mysqli(DB_HOST, DB_USERNAME, DB_PASSWORD, DB_NAME);

if(!$mysqli){
    die("Connection failed: " . $mysqli->error);
}

$query = sprintf("SELECT name, humidity, ph, degree FROM dataklm");
$result = $mysqli -> query($query);
$data = array();
foreach ($result as $row) {
  $data[] = $row;
}

$result->close();
$mysqli->close();
print json_encode($data);
```

i've success retrieve data with above code, but i want select them per id. i just tried like below. but it's not work

```
$query = sprintf("SELECT name, humidity, ph, degree FROM dataklm WHERE id='$_GET['id']");
```

i passed data to this

```
<?php
include 'header.php';
include 'conn.php';
?>
<html>
<style type="text/css">
            #chart-container {
                width: 1000px;
                height: 1000px;
            }
        </style>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="jumbotron">
        <h1 class="display-3" style="text-align:center;">Smartfish</h1>
        <p class="lead" style="text-align:center;">Monitoring System</p>
        </div>
    </div>
        <body>
            <div id="chart-container">
                <canvas id="mycanvas"></canvas>
            </div>
            <script src="./assets/chart.js"> </script>
            <script src="./app.js"> </script>
        </body>
</html>
```

Comment: try this        **$id = $_GET['id'];**                                                        **$query = sprintf("SELECT name, humidity, ph, degree FROM dataklm WHERE id='$id' ");**

Comment: Your code is vulnerable to SQL injection - I would recommend using parameterized query.

Comment: @SushankPokharel Undefined index "id" sir, even i've set the id

Comment: @Fawwaz can you show the code how you have passed the id to this page.

Comment: @SushankPokharel i add the code above.

Comment: @Fawwaz I have provided the answer below.

Answer (score -1):

I didn't find anything that is passing the id from your html page to the php page.

Pass the id from html to php page as:-

```
<a href="detail1.php?id=<?php echo $result['id']; ?>">view more</a>
```

Doing this you will be passing an id from url to the next page. and you can get this id by using **GET** method as

```
$id = $_GET['id'];
```

then use your query.

Hope this will help you.

Comment: you added basically the same answer here https://stackoverflow.com/a/47375194/1415724 you need to delete one

Comment: @Fred-ii- It's was a mistake. Just due to net problem it didn't show my first answer so I posted the answer again. I have deleted the one answer.

Answer (score -2):

If you write the "$_GET['id']" just like this in the string it's gonna be threated as a string.

```
$query = sprintf("SELECT name, humidity, ph, degree FROM dataklm WHERE id='".$_GET['id']."'");
```

Comment: If it's Undefined index then the "id" not been set in the url.

Comment: it's set sir, after i add that code my data isn't encode as json anymore.

Comment: This leaves you **wide open** to SQL injection attacks.  **You will be hacked** if you use this method.  Never concatenate arbitrary data into an SQL query.  Use prepared/parameterized queries instead to avoid this problem.